# Float32 to UInt16 terracing problem

Tags: qgis, dem, lidar, gdal-translate, unity3d

I have the same initial problem as the links below, but I cannot change to using float32 as I am not using Blender.

[Terracing / stepping artefacts after converting lidar DTM from float32 to uint16](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/421660/terracing-stepping-artefacts-after-converting-lidar-dtm-from-float32-to-uint16)

[Terracing and data format issues when converting DEM from float32 to UInt16](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/440874/terracing-and-data-format-issues-when-converting-dem-from-float32-to-uint16)

This command works, but is still in float32 so can't be used in Unity:

```
"gdal_translate.exe" –of ENVI –outsize 4096 4096 -r lanczos "DTM_SU9075_P_10735_20210218_20210418.tif" "For_UnityNo16conv.raw"
```

When I change to UInt16 the terracing occurs:

```
"gdal_translate.exe" –ot UInt16 –scale –of ENVI –outsize 4096 4096 -r lanczos "DTM_SU9075_P_10735_20210218_20210418.tif" "For_UnityScaleAttempt.raw"
```

So I tried adding values to the scale, but I think the input are whole numbers so whole meters without centimetres?
The minimum and maximum elevations are:
STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=90.249000549316
STATISTICS_MINIMUM=13.739999771118

So surely there are enough values in 65,536 to create a smooth height model. I just can't seem to scale it correctly.

This is clearly wrong [edit:actually what is clearly wrong is just providing scale without the units] and results in stepping artefact/terracing:

```
"gdal_translate.exe" –ot UInt16 –scale 13 97 0 65535 –of ENVI –outsize 4096 4096 -r lanczos "DTM_SU9075_P_10735_20210218_20210418.tif" "For_UnityScaleAttempt.raw"
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

(As an aside I'm no longer resizing as I am cropping first)

Comment: How is this a different issue from https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/440874/terracing-and-data-format-issues-when-converting-dem-from-float32-to-uint16 ?

Comment: I guess it isn't, but that question is essentially solved (but with a solution not relevant here) - the link within one of the answers shows someone importing into Blender with no conversion and the other question I linked to says that Blender supports float32 so no conversion is needed. Unity doesn't support float32 so this would need solving at the gdal stage if possible.

Comment: It is also a different workflow as they are not using the scale function of gdal_translate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing the scale parameters as in my third code example works. I was expecting the gdal_translate to preserve units but change potential precision. It doesn't. The scale can be assigned to elevation in Unity.