# Is there a DEM WCS for the whole globe?

Tags: dem, srtm, wcs, service-recommendations

I've found some for a few individual places, but I am struggling to find one for the whole globe.

- North America | https://elevation.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/services/3DEPElevation/ImageServer/WCSServer?request=GetCapabilities&service=WCS, from https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/item/543e6b86e4b0fd76af69cf4c
- Australia | http://services.ga.gov.au/gis/services/DEM_SRTM_1Second_Hydro_Enforced/MapServer/WCSServer?request=GetCapabilities&service=WCS , from https://data.gov.au/dataset/ds-ga-aac46307-fce8-449d-e044-00144fdd4fa6/distribution/dist-ga-aac46307-fce8-449d-e044-00144fdd4fa6-4/details?q=
- Italy | http://wms.pcn.minambiente.it/wcs/dtm_20m?service=WCS&request=GetCapabilities, from https://www.opendem.info/opendemeu_meta_italy.html
- EU | https://geoservice.dlr.de/eoc/elevation/wcs?SERVICE=WCS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities, from https://geoservice.dlr.de/web/services

By the way, I am also interested if you have URLs for additional individual countries. Also, for future reference, substituting GetCapabilities for GetCoverage returns different results sometimes. Worth trying if you are getting errors.

Comment: `substituting GetCapabilities for GetCoverage returns different results sometimes` it should always return different results.  GetCapabilities tell the client what operations are available and names of the coverages.  GetCoverage gets you the coverage data.  Or do you mean that the URL to retrieve data through a GetCoverage request may not be the same as the URL to get the capabilities? There's nothing wrong with that, clients should always parse the GetCapabilities response to see the URLS for other operations

Comment: @nmtoken I'm not knowledgeable about code, I just found from plain ol' trial and error that sometimes you get the exact same result, and sometimes you get different ones, depending on source.

Answer (score -1):

[Since QGIS 3.24](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog324/index.html#feature-add-out-of-the-box-connection-to-mapzen-global-terrain-tiles), there is a preinstalled connection via [XYZ tiles](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/opening_data.html#using-xyz-tile-services) to a global DEM: [Mapzen Global Terrain](https://registry.opendata.aws/terrain-tiles/). You can use it from the remote source or also download the data by right clicking the layer > Export to use it locally.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to source WCS instead of WMS because the latter was compressing the image to 0-255 color depth, but it seems that the workflow for getting uncompressed images from WCS is more involved than just exporting. In the end, both of them resulted in compressed color TIFs which were unusable for displacement maps in Blender - they resulted in banding/terracing. I ended up downloading the TIFs, merging and converting them to Uint 16 bits ([link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/421660/terracing-stepping-artefacts-after-converting-lidar-dtm-from-float32-to-uint16)).