Blender DEM Visualisation
I am experimenting with new GIS tools, and one of them is Blender. I am trying to visualize a DEM, and everything works fine, except for the strange contour-like stripes appearing in the DEM. I’m not sure why they are there since the DEM is in high resolution (1 m). I even smoothed the layer using Focal Statistics in ArcGIS Pro.



The DEM was likely converted from a floating point to integer datatype (thus getting rounded). https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/421660/terracing-stepping-artefacts-after-converting-lidar-dtm-from-float32-to-uint16
